How to execute the visual studio specific linker.exe from the MSBUILD script
I am in a situation to call the "linker.exe" during the C# project (.csproj) build. If I am building the C# project with Visual studio 2019, then I want to execute the Visual Studio 2019 linker, or if I am building with Visual Studio 2022 then i want to execute the Visual Studio 2022 linker. I have tried below approaches, but all of them are failing to find the visual studio specific link.exe.
1- <Link task in msbuild - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/link-task?view=vs-2022
Its failing, and throwing error - error MSB4018: Microsoft.Build.Shared.InternalErrorException: MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: link.exe unexpectedly not a rooted path. Not able to locate the linker.exe.
2- Tried executing the linker.exe by executing the linker.exe using the <Exec Command="link
Again, it throws error - 'link' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
Then I tried to initialize the Visual Studio environment by calling the vcvars64.bat batch file. This batch file is getting executed successfully, but after this If I call the <Exec Command="link then it throws the error - 'link' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
So, it will be great if anybody knows how to execute the <Link task in msbuild without any errors.
Or
how to execute the linker.exe by calling the <Exec Command="link.

There is no linker for C#. link.exe is for C/C++. The task documentation that you referenced states “This task is only available when using the C++ build system.”

@JonathanDodds : I know its not for C#, but I am looking for a hack, Hence I mentioned, I am in a situation to call the linker.exe.
I want to link the C# and the C++ assemblies together into a single executable. As described in the :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738014/calling-c-link-from-a-csproj-in-vs2008
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609056/how-to-link-c-sharp-and-c-assemblies-into-a-single-executable

For both C# and C++ there is a layer of "project support" that is written in MSBuild that is used by .csproj and .vcxproj files. Part of the project support is determining the locations of the appropriate tools. The project support is different and incompatible for C# and C++, especially SDK style .csproj files. In theory, you could reverse engineer the .vcxproj project to develop custom code, equivalent to what the .vcxproj project does, for your .csproj to support the Link task. But this may be impractical.

As @Jonathan says,"This task is only available when using the C++ build system.”
link.exe is specific to C++ projects in Visual Studio. For C# projects in Visual Studio, you typically don't use link.exe.
As alternatives, if you want to combines the object files into a single executable file, you can check the following methods:
1.Use Single-file deployment feature.
 <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

2.Using ILMerge
<Target Name="ILMerge">
    <!-- the ILMergePath property points to the location of ILMerge.exe console application -->
    <Exec Command="$(ILMergeConsolePath) /out:Merged.dll File1.dll File2.dll" />
  </Target>

Docs Referred:
PublishSingleFile
ILMerge

Thanks for the comment.
Actually, I want to link the C# and the C++ assemblies together into a single executable. As described in the :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738014/calling-c-link-from-a-csproj-in-vs2008
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609056/how-to-link-c-sharp-and-c-assemblies-into-a-single-executable

I am able to do it if I execute the linker using the <Exec task from the csproj file.
I thought to call the linker using the <Link task in the msbuild, but it always throws the error, I know its for C++. But I am looking for any hack which I can invoke from the C# csproj if I import any other prop or target file.

Ok, i see. If you type link.exe in Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt, will you see the linker information like this. Try to add C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\Hostx64\x64 into your environment path and run your <Exec task to see if the issue persists.(e.g:https://i.sstatic.net/7odE3Hje.png)

Yes, I am able to get the linker. I am executing the batch file (vcvars64.bat) to initialize the  shell with the visual studio environment and then executing the linker.
Thanks for the suggestions.

Do you mean the  <Exec Command="link item"  still  throws the error  even you are able to get the linker and execute the batch file ?
